# axios responses with text/html only on production nodeJs express server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have a react app where i'm calling an express route

```
try {
      const {data: { data }} = await axios.get("/api/customer/companyId",{params: { companyId }});
      console.log(data); // here data is text/html only on production
catch (error) {
     console.log(error)
      }
```

And the express function looks like this:

```
exports.getCustomer = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { companyId } = req.query;
  const doc = await Customer.findOne({ companyId: companyId }).populate(
    "customerDeals"
  );
  winston.debug(doc);
  // if user with this companyI does not exists
  if (!doc) return next(new AppError(`CompanyId: ${companyId} not found`, 404));

  res.status(200).json({
    status: "success",
    data: doc,
  });
});
```

Now in dev mode , i'm getting the response json as expected , but on production im getting html/text, why is that?

Comment: Have you tried adding `"Accept": "application/json"` header to your axios HTTP request?

Comment: i'm also sending params ,so should i add the headers like so : await axios.get("/api/customer/companyId", {
        params: { companyId },
        headers: { Accept: "application/json" },
      });

Comment: Yes, that's how you do it.

Comment: Thank you , the problem is i have different routs so i will need to add the "Accept" header to each and every one? can i specify the content type as application/json for an express router?

Comment: You can add these headers to all axios requests using [request interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors).